# Kibana logs getting truncated when content is too large

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, opensearch, fluent-bit

I'm encountering an issue with Kibana where logs seem to be getting truncated when they contain large content. The logs are being ingested into Amazon Opensearch with fluent bit from K8s cluster, and I'm using Kibana to visualize and analyze them. However, when the log messages have extensive content, it appears that something is cutting them off, and I'm unable to view the complete message.
This is the input.conf from fluent bit configuration :

```
[INPUT]
    Name              tail
    Tag               kube.*
    Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
    Parser            docker
    DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit     256MB
    Buffer_Max_Size   64k
    Skip_Long_Lines   On
    Refresh_Interval  10
```

Opensearch version: Elasticsearch 7.10

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so, what could be the potential reasons for this truncation? Are there any configuration settings in Kibana, Fluent-bit or Elasticsearch that need to be adjusted to handle larger log messages without truncation?

I appreciate any insights or solutions that can help resolve this issue.

I tried to change Buffer_Max_Size from 32k to 64k but it did not help.